# IIS 7.5 no static or dynamic compression

Tags: iis-7.5, asp-classic, compression

I can't get static or dynamic compression to work on a new server for .ASP, .JS or .CSS files.

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit.  Under IIS Role Services, I have ASP installed, as well as static and dynamic compression.  I'm using DefaultAppPool with the standard ApplicationPoolIdentity.  I've enabled all the compression options for the site.

Here's the relevant section of my applicationHost.config (this is all under system.webServer):

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>

<serverRuntime frequentHitThreshold="1" />

<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
```

So I turned on failed request tracing to get a better view.

For ASP, it appears to skip static and dynamic compression entirely.  There is no entry for DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_SUCCESS or DYNAMIC COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS.

For CSS and JS, it attempts static compression but fails:

```
STATIC_COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS     Reason="NO_MATCHING_SCHEME"
```

I can't find any solid documentation online about what NO_MATCHING_SCHEME means.  Help!